# How to get the top X items in the active folder based on the current view

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to find a way of getting the top X (say 10) mail items in the current folder based on the sort order and filters the user may have applied.

The main issue is that the folder's Items collection gives all of the mail items in date order and there is no obvious way to sort and filter the collection based on the current view.

```vb
Sub foo()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objFolder = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set objItem = objFolder.Items(i)
        Debug.Print objItem.Subject
    Next i

End Sub
```

It would be great if someone would point me to the correct places in the Outlook object model so that I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right avenue. There is a difference between the view and the `Items` collection which you are trying to use in the code.

To get the filter applied on the UI you need to use the following sequence of property and method calls:

```
Explorer.CurrentView.SortFields
```

The [CurrentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.currentview) property of the Explorer or Folder class returns an object representing the current view. The View object allows you to create customizable views that allow you to better sort, group and ultimately view data of all different types. There are a variety of different view types that provide the flexibility needed to create and maintain your important data. Views are defined and customized using the View object's `XML` property. The `XML` property allows you to create and set a customized XML schema that defines the various features of a view.

The [View.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.filter) property returns or sets a string value that represents the filter for a view. The value of this property is a string, in DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) syntax, that represents the current filter for the view. For more information about using DASL syntax to filter items in a view, see [Filtering Items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items).

Also, you can cast the `View` object to the `TableView` and use its properties for detecting the sorting mechanisms. The [SortFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.tableview.sortfields) property returns an [OrderFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.orderfields) object that represents the set of fields by which the items displayed in the `TableView` object are ordered.

So, then you can apply the filter retrieved to the `Items` collection to get the right order. Or the opposite, to set the order in the Outlook UI.

```
Private Sub FilterViewToLastWeek()  
 Dim objView As View 
 ' Obtain a View object reference to the current view.  
 Set objView = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentView 
 ' Set a DASL filter string, using a DASL macro, to show  
 ' only those items that were received last week.  
 objView.Filter = "%lastweek(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"")%" 
 ' Save and apply the view.  
 objView.Save  
 objView.Apply  
End Sub
```

Finally, I'd suggest observing the [View.XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.view.xml) property which returns or sets a String value that specifies the XML definition of the current view. The XML definition describes the view type by using a series of tags and keywords corresponding to various properties of the view itself. When the view is created, the XML definition is parsed to render the settings for the new view.

To determine how the XML should be structured when creating views, you can create a view by using the Outlook user interface and then you can retrieve the XML property for that view.

Comment: When I try to read the `View.Filter` property, via either `ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.Filter` or `ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.View.Filter`, they both return an empty string even though a filter is applied. Please would you give some more direction on how to read from this property?

Comment: You may try to cast the `View` object to the `TableView` class and use its properties such as `SortFields`.

Comment: Did you try to check the `XML` property of the view?

Comment: Casting the `View` to a `TableView` does give me access to properties such as `Sortfields`. These properties do give me information about the sort order but there is no information about the filter. I also investigated the `View.XML` property and the xml string does provide information about the sorting but I cannot see any information on the filtering. I think at this point I have enough information to be able to produce a solution which caters for the sorting but not the filtering. The sticking point here seems to be that `View.Filter` is returning an empty string for me.

Comment: Have you tried to overview the `XML` property value?

Comment: Okay, I managed to get `View.Filter` property working by applying a filter on the View tab of the ribbon and editing the view settings. It's not quite what I am looking for. The "filtering" I want to account for is the filter applied by the user when they do a search. For example, on the Home tab they go to the Find section and choose Filter Email > Has Attachments.

Comment: Also, you may check out the `Folder.View` property.

Comment: I have already checked these and the `View` object does not seem to provide the filter information based on the filtering the user has applied through the Filter Email dropdown on the ribbon. Since I now realize that the title of my original post is misleading (it includes the term "current view") it may be the case that I need to start a new question.